# How to do configuration of a python environment

Tags: python, django, configuration

During the last years I mostly used django. Django uses the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to find its configuration.

Now I have a project where I don't use django and I would like to have a clean and easy to understand way to load the configuration.

Example:

I want a global boolean to turn debugging on or off:

```
settings.DEBUG
```

I guess there are thousands of ways to do it.

But what is the most pythonic way to store and load project settings?

... maybe the Python community already settled on a well known default way I just don't know yet.

Comment: @Matt This question is not supposed to be closed. Asking for the pythonic way to do something is a generally accepted kind of question on this network.

Comment: Agreed, voted for reopen

Comment: @theblizz There is no common definition of "Pythonic" so when people ask for "Pythonic" anything they are asking for answers that will accord with each individual's opinion of what they consider to be "Pythonic". Besides, this question is also too broad. I've seen dozens of ways to load configurations. Different project and needs call for different solutions. The OP here has not specified any concrete constraints (other than "Pythonic" which is not a constraint at all).

Comment: @Louis is "follows the zen of python" better. I think this is a common definition. What do you think?

Comment: @guettli Just as subjective, and this does not take care of the broadness of the question.

Comment: @Louis imagine there is a default and well-known solution to solve my issue. Then this question would have been answered after some minutes and everything would be fine. But that is not the case. Every python application does its own configuration handling (django, salt, zope, ...). The question looks subjective and broad because the environment is like it is. I see it like this: the environment is subjective and broad - the question is valid and simple.

Answer (score 2):

From: https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html

Use the global immutable constant

```
__debug__
```

This constant is true if Python was not started with an -O option.

If you mean to set the logging level, use `logging.setLevel(lvl)`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel

*Update:*

For general global constants I would use a singleton, i.e. a module, to store the constants you need. I.e. create a module `config.py`

```
DEBUG = False
OTHER_THING = True
```

From other modules you can

```
import config
print(config.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the most pythonic way would be to use the [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html). It provides the different access protocols one may need, as well as different adapters (JSON for instance).

Moreover, it allows easy customization, is fully documented, and it is integrated in other facilities such as the `logging`.

The example of the `logging` facilities using `ConfigParser`for the file configuration is on the [logging manual pages](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-fileformat). I usually keep a separate file for the logging configuration but it could be done using a single file for the entire project.

Comment: It is also language agnostic so that configuration managers don't need any knowledge of Python to use it.

Comment: Please elaborate "it .. integrates nicely with other facilities such as the logging". The docs of ConfigParser don't contain the word "logging".

Comment: You are right, it is the other way around, `logging` uses `ConfigParser`, so the docs are on the first.